# Expand English language contractions with pycontraction library

Tags: python

This is my code.

```
from pycontractions import Contractions

cont = Contractions('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')
cont.load_models()
```

It gives the following error:

```
Word2Vec model not found at GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin
```

I have installed pycontractions, gensim and Word2Vec.
What else is missing?

Comment: You may need to give the full path to the .bin file if it isn't in the current working directory.